# How does Krieg the Psycho's 'Salt the Wound' skill add stacks?

Tags: borderlands-2

Krieg the Psycho's '[Salt the Wound](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Salt_the_Wound)' skill in the Mania skill tree is described as:

> When Krieg takes damage while his shield is down, it adds a stack of Salt the Wound to a maximum of 20. Krieg's melee damage and shotgun damage increase for every stack accumulated.

How exactly will Krieg get a stack added with Salt the Wound? Is it based on  the amount of damage dealt to him? Or how long he's being damaged? What corresponds to one stack added?

How do I make getting Salt the Wound stacks faster?

I also would like to know if items like the [Skin of the Ancients](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Skin_of_the_Ancients) relic, which increase resistance to damage from various elements and including non-elemental damage, could lessen the speed at which Krieg gets Salt the Wound stacks.

Answer (score 1):

I have only just started playing Krieg, but from the description I would be inclined to believe it means after krieg's shield hits 0, any damage taken will add a stack of salt the wound.

It most likely will pop up an icon just above the xp bar like bloodlust and anarchy and all other temorary skills/stacks.

As for what damage will add a stack and won't, I believe it will work on bullet impacts, enemy melee attacks, and radial damage (explosions).

What I'm less sure of, is whether or not it will add a stack for each "tic" of damage off of a DoT like burn or caustic status effects krieg is suffering from.

I also wonder if the Rough Rider shield (capacity 0), combined with being shot many times by a much lower lv opponent who could not likely kill him; would result in Krieg getting to that full stack of 20 in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Know what the unit conversion is (even just an approximation)? What unit (amount of damage, projectiles, time being damaged, etc.) correlates to one 'Salt the Wound' stack?

Comment: I just started another semester at college, so I can't play much now; but last I did play (3 weeks back) it seemed like every bullet impacting him added a stack. It filled to 20 pretty quick once the shield dropped, and in Buzzaxe Rampage my health was constantly re-filling from every melee, and the shield stayed down from all the bullets I was taking.